# How to access object in thymeleaf block?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm showing a table content as follows. Note especially how `*{id}` maps automatically to the `row` content:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
    <th:block th:each="row : ${content}">
        <tr th:object="${row}">
            <td th:text="*{id}/>
            <td th:text="${#temporals.format(row.thedate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}">
                2017-08-07 20:01:52
            </td>
        </tr>
    </th:block>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Question: how can I rewrite the `#temporals` expression to also use implicit reference to the row? Eg, the following does not work:

```
<td th:text="${#temporals.format(*{thedate}, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}">
```

Why is `*{thedate}` expression not working here?

Comment: did you try `th:with`?

Comment: `th:with="withdate=*{thedate}"` works indeed, but I'd like to achieve the same without `th:with`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

```
<td th:text="*{#temporals.format(thedate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}">
```

See the example in the thymeleaf docs: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#order-details